# How can I prove the following statement: "$\mu (E) =0 $ implies $E $ is in a certain class of sets"?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $\mathbb {X}  $ to be  the class of all sets $E $ that satisfy  $\mu(E)=\sup \{\mu (K):K \subset E, K $ compact$\}   $

Then claim that $\mu (E)=0 $ imply $E \in \mathbb {X } $

*What is it really I have to prove, to show that this implication is true.?*

---

$\mu $ is defined as $\mu (E) = \inf \{\mu(V), E \subset V, V $open $\}$ and $\mu(V) $, for $V $ open, is defined as $\mu (V)=\sup \{\Lambda f :f \prec V \} $

Where $\Lambda $ is a positive linear functional on the vector space of continuous functions on $X $ with compact support.

---

Thus if  $\mu(E)=0 $ then  $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists V :\mu(V)< \epsilon $

But then for this particular $V $ we have that  $\sup \{\Lambda f :f \prec V \}= \epsilon $ $\implies \Lambda f =0 $ for every $f \prec V $. Thus $f=0 $.

I don't know where this leads thoug... So need help with the question above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always we have $$\mu (A)\geq \sup\{\mu (K) :K\subset A\}$$ so it enough to show the reverse inequality. But if $\mu (A) =0$ then the reverse inequality follows from the fact that empty set is compact.

Comment: I don't understand the last claim. How can $0< \sup \{ \mu (K) : K \subset A \} $, We have that $\emptyset $ is in the set which we take the supremum over, and that $\mu( \emptyset) =0 $, but does this imply the supremum is $> 0 $? What if we would have $\mu (K)=0 $ for every $K $ in the set?

Comment: if $\mu (A) =0 $ then $\sup\{\mu (K) :K\subset A\} \leq 0$